# How to override ionic custom CSS using [ngStyle]

Tags: css, sass, ionic4

How to override ionic custom CSS using `[ngStyle]`

I have tried below code but it's not working:

```
[ngStyle]="{'--color': 'blue'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use "**!important**" to override ionic custom CSS .

However , it's bad practice and it will not work with **[ngStyle]**.

Instead of using !important in **[ngStyle]** you can use it like this :

```
[attr.style]="'--color:blue !important'"
```

Comment: yes using !important we can override this is possible using css that i know..but i want to override color using ngStyle

Comment: tired not working in console it showing like this:     unsafe: ;

Comment: removing -- it works..but to override ionic 4 custom property we need --

Comment: yess i see , have you tried this ^^  [ngStyle]="--color: red;color: var(--color);"
sry i don't see any other alternative solution but i'm trying my best to help

Comment: yes tried everything.. anyways thanks a lot for your help :)